# How do I change this to make an if statement for showing up on Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am having trouble with some code that I have. I am making a donation page for my website and I am not sure how to go about a part of it showing up for the "item_name" part of it. I have several options for the possible donations and I would like to show the option they chose showing up in the item_name when they are being redirected to pay. This is what I have:

```
        $price = '6.50';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 1) //Price for package 1 (Regular Donator)
        $price = '6.50';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 2) //Price for package 2 (Extreme Donator)
        $price = '12.50';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 3) //Price for package 3 (10 SoF Spins)
        $price = '2.50';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 4) //Price for package 4 (20 SoF Spins)
        $price = '4.00';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 5) //Price for package 5 (Fight Kiln Completion)
        $price = '5.50';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 6) //Price for package 6 (1 Ragged Gold Key)
        $price = '2.00';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 7) //Price for package 7 (4 Ragged Gold Keys)
        $price = '9.99';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 8) //Price for package 8 (12 Ragged Gold Keys)
        $price = '20.00';
    if($_GET['prod'] == 9) //Price for package 9 (28 Ragged Gold Keys)
        $price = '40.00';

  $p->add_field('custom', $_GET['username']);
  $p->add_field('business', 'dtordik@gmail.com'); //edit to your email
  $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success');
  $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
  $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
  $p->add_field('item_name', 'Package '.$_GET['prod']);
  $p->add_field('item_number', $_GET['prod']);
  $p->add_field('currency_code', 'USD');
  $p->add_field('amount', $price);
  //$p->add_field('quantity', $_GET['amm']);
  $p->add_field('lc', 'GB');
  $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
  //$p->dump_fields();      // for debugging, output a table of all the fields
  break;
```

You see the **$p->add_field('item_name', 'Package '.$_GET['prod']);** which grabs the number and it then shows up on the paypal website as "Package 1." How can I make it so that if someone chose 'prod' 1, it could come up as "Regular Donator," 'prod' 2 as "Extreme Donator" and so on. I do not know if I am over-thinking something or not but any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit inefficient, if you optimize the solution will be straight forward.

Define a list of all your products, their price and their label.

```
$products = array(
    1 => array(
        "price" => "6.00",
        "label" => "Regular Donator"
    ),
    2 => array(
        "price" => "60.00",
        "label" => "Extreme Donator"
    ),
    3 => array(
        "price" => "0.00",
        "label" => "Cheap bastard"
    )
);

$product = $_GET["prod"];
$price = $products[$product]["price"];
$label = $products[$product]["label"];

$p->add_field('item_name', $label);
$p->add_field('item_number', $product);
$p->add_field('amount', $price);
// etc
```